# FreeSWTICH Language Bundle Customization

Tags: freeswitch, ivr, spidermonkey, debian-packaging

We are working on a IVR development for a native location. We are required to play the Date and Time, Numbers and other dynamic information's using Language Bundle. We are searching for the Source Code of Language Bundle to Customize it and create it for our native language.

Whether we can able to customize the Language Bundle? If, yes any one provide us the process/document to create it. If any link available regarding this, kindly share it with us. Since we can't able to find any information related to customization of language bundle in below free switch link,

https://developer.signalwire.com/freeswitch/FreeSWITCH-Explained/